# Picking maximum number of nodes from network so that none are connected by 1 degree

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I have the following network or graph problem.

From a network, pick the maximum number of nodes such that no nodes are connected by 1 degree. For example, from a network given by these edges:

```
a - b
b - c
```

I could pick `b`, or I could pick `a` and `c`. `c` would be better.

Is there a name for this network problem? What algorithms could I use to solve it?

Comment: It's an *maximum independent set* problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory) In general case it's **NP-complete**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to be the [Independent Set Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_set_(graph_theory)), which is the complement of the [Clique Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem), i.e. finding a subset of nodes in the graph such that each node is directly connected to all the other nodes in that subset.

You can reduce your problem to the clique problem by "inverting" the graph, i.e. adding edges between all non-connected nodes, and removing all the old edges, then finding a [maximum clique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem#Finding_maximum_cliques_in_arbitrary_graphs) of that [complement graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_graph).

The problem is NP-complete, though there seem to be some clever algorithm with a rather "low" base to the exponent. If a sub-optimal solution is also acceptable, you could just try Greedy, selecting the nodes with the lowest number of edges (in the original graph) first, addind more low-degree nodes that are not connected to any of the nodes picked so-far.

Comment: It's *maximum independent set* problem; you are quite right: the problem can be solved via *maximum clique* on the *complement* graph.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Right, thanks, I could not think of the correct term.